# Laravel ManytoMany Relationship not working with the filamentPHP

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i am trying to save data to DB using laravel but getting the following error.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::getOwnerKeyName()
```

Here is my Model BlogCategory Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class blogcategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'blog_category_title',
        'blog_category_slug'
    ];

public function blogpost(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(blogpost::class);
}
}
```

Here is my Blog Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class blogpost extends Model
{

use HasFactory;
protected $fillable = [
    'blog_post_title',
    'blog_post_slug',
    'blog_post_thumbnail',
    'blog_post_body',
    'blog_post_active',
    'blog_post_published_at',
    'user_id',
];
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function blogtitle(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(blogtitle::class);
}

public function blogcategory(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany(blogcategory::class);
}
}
```

i am using FIlament PHP to store data into DB.

here is my all tables name use with the following Model

1. Blog Post Table - store all blogs
2. Blog Category Table - store all category
3. BlogcategoryBlogpost Table - store relationship between category and table.

Here is my filament PHP code to store the data using forms

```
Select::make('category_id')
                    ->relationship('blogcategory', 'blog_category_title')
                    ->required(),
```

Need Help

Comment: Where did you define the method getOwnerKeyName() ?

Comment: This is not a method, this comes in error